# Firebase Cloud Function Called on Endless Loop

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is used to send emails and it is hosted in the affiliated Firebase app. The timeout is set to 60 seconds and it is invoked via https request. However, when the request is made from the UI, it is invoked every 60 seconds and then times out, even though it sends the email.

**Component.ts** - form submit action

```
      onSubmit() {
          this.cloudService.sendEmail(
              this.model.name,
              this.model.email,
              this.model.message
          );
        }
```

**CloudFunctionService.ts**

```
    export class CloudFunctionService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      sendEmail(name, email, message) {
        const url = 'https://url/path/to/function';

        const params = new HttpParams()
          .set('name', name)
          .set('email', email)
          .set('message', message);

        return this.http.get(url, {params}).toPromise()
          .then(res => {
            // this line never gets hit
            console.log(res);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // this line never gets hit
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    }
```

**index.ts** - typescript code for function

```
    import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
    import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
    import * as cors from 'cors';
    const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});

    export const sendContactMail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      corsHandler(request, response, () => { console.log('cors handled')});

      const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
      sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
      sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers('{{','}}');

      const msg = {
        to: 'some@email.com',
        from: 'some.other@email.com',
        templateId: 'mytemplateid',
        substitutions: {
          name: request.query.name,
          email: request.query.email,
          message: request.query.message
        }
      };

        sgMail.send(msg).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
           }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });

        response.send();
    });
```

**Firebase Function Log**

[Phantom re-triggered every 60s only to time out again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkqS9.png)

[Even though I am receiving the emails from the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGzC4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP type functions must send a response to the client in order to complete the function.  Your function isn't sending anything to the client within the default timeout, so Cloud Functions has to assume that it failed.  It may also then be retrying the function since it was assumed to fail.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().

Comment: Not sure why this did not come up in my documentation search, but that was the trick. I will update my OP with the working function code